REACT USE CONTEXT | Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: login is not a function
I'm having a problem when I try to consume data from my AuthContext provider when I call the login function
index.tsx:53 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: login is not a function
    at handleLogin (index.tsx:53:19)
    at onClick (index.tsx:108:54)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4164:14)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:16)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:31)
    at invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError (react-dom.development.js:4291:25)
    at executeDispatch (react-dom.development.js:9041:3)
    at processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder (react-dom.development.js:9073:7)
    at processDispatchQueue (react-dom.development.js:9086:5)
    at dispatchEventsForPlugins (react-dom.development.js:9097:3)
    at eval (react-dom.development.js:9288:12)
    at batchedUpdates$1 (react-dom.development.js:26174:12)
    at batchedUpdates (react-dom.development.js:3991:12)
    at dispatchEventForPluginEventSystem (react-dom.development.js:9287:3)
    at dispatchEventWithEnableCapturePhaseSelectiveHydrationWithoutDiscreteEventReplay (react-dom.development.js:6465:5)
    at dispatchEvent (react-dom.development.js:6457:5)
    at dispatchDiscreteEvent (react-dom.development.js:6430:5)

Below I put the dependencies and versions of the tools I am using
/package.json
  "axios": "^1.7.2",
    "chart.js": "^4.4.3",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.19.2",
    "ionicons": "^5.5.4",
    "next": "^14.2.4",
    "nookies": "^2.5.2",
    "react": "^18",
    "react-chartjs-2": "^5.2.0",
    "react-data-table-component": "^7.6.2",
    "react-dom": "^18",

/src/context/AutherContext.tsx
import React, { createContext, useEffect, ReactNode, useContext, useState } from "react";
import { setupApiClient } from "../services/api";
import { destroyCookie, setCookie, parseCookies } from "nookies";
import Router from "next/router";


interface AuthContextData {
  isAuthenticated: boolean;
  login: (credentials: LoginData) => void;
  logout: () => void;
  credentials?: LoginData
}

interface LoginData {
  email: string,
  password: string,
}


interface AuthProviderProps {
  children: ReactNode
}

export function logout() {

  console.log("fechando ...")
}

export const AuthContext = createContext({} as AuthContextData)

export function AuthProvider({ children }: AuthProviderProps) {

  const [user, setUser] = useState<LoginData>()
  const isAuthenticated = !!user

  async function login({ email, password }: LoginData) {

    const api = setupApiClient()

    if (email && password) {

      const response = await api.post('/user/login', {
        email,
        password
      })
      //    RECUPERAR DADOS DO OBJECTO RESPONSE
      const { id, name, tipo, token } = response.data

      // configurando cookies
      setCookie(undefined, '@dados.token', token, {
        maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 * 30, // expira 1 mês   
        path: "/"  // caminhos que terão acesso ao cookies
      })

      // configuracao cookie id
      setCookie(undefined, '@dados.id', id, {
        maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 * 30, // expira 1 mês   
        path: "/"  // caminhos que terão acesso ao cookies
      })
      setUser({
        email,
        password
      })

      console.log("login : " + token)
      //  Passar o token para todas requisições
      api.defaults.headers['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${token}`
    }
  }
    return (
      <AuthContext.Provider value={{ isAuthenticated, login, logout }}>
        {children}
      </AuthContext.Provider>
    )

  }


/src/page/admin/index.tsx
import { AuthContext } from '@/context/AutherContext';
import {
    ArrowLeftIcon,
    EnvelopeIcon,
    EyeIcon,
    EyeSlashIcon,
    KeyIcon
} from "@heroicons/react/16/solid";


export default function Login() {

    
   const { login } = useContext(AuthContext)
    const [inputs, setInptus] = useState(
        {
            email: "",
            password: "",
        }
    )
    const [showpassword, setpassword] = useState<boolean>(false)

    const showPassword = () => {

        if (showpassword === false) {
            setpassword(true)
        }
        else {
            setpassword(false)
        }
    }

   function myteste(e: any) {

    e.preventDefault();


    // testMail.setNome(inputs.email)

    // console.log(testMail)
    // console.log(useContext(AuthContext))
 
    }
    async function handleLogin(e: Event) {
        // alert("credentials : " + inputs.email  + "  pass: " + inputs.password)
        e.preventDefault();

        if (inputs.email != "" || inputs.password != "") {
            // console.log("my datas : " +  {...inputs})
            await login({...inputs})
        }
        console.log("campos vazios ...")
    }

    return (<div className='login-main h-screen w-screen'>
            <div className='lg:container xs:flex xs:flex-col md:flex md:flex-col login mx-auto py-20'>
                <div className='flex flex-col justify-center items-center bx-main gap-2 mx-auto '>
                    {/* LOGO */}
                    <div className='flex justify-center items-center mb-4'>
                        <Image
                            src="/admin/logo.svg"
                            width={405}
                            height={309}
                            alt="web"
                            layout='responsive'
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div className='flex flex-col justify-center w-3/5 items-center gap-5'>
                        {/* formulario  onSubmit={(e: any) => myteste(e)} */}
                        <form className='flex flex-col justify-center  items-center gap-5'>
                            {/* email */}
                            <div className='bx-inputs flex flex-row items-center gap-1 justify-start'>
                                <EnvelopeIcon className='w-9 h-7 text-primary' />
                                {/* <p className='tipografia font-bold text-xl text-primary'>E-mail</p> */}
                                <input type="email" name="firstName"
                                    placeholder='E-mail'
                                    className="inputs  tipografia font-bold text-base"
                                    value={inputs.email}
                                    required={true}
                                    onChange={(e) => setInptus({ ...inputs, email: e.target.value })}
                                />
                            </div>
                            {/* password */}
                            <div className='bx-inputs flex flex-row items-center'>
                                <KeyIcon className='w-9 h-7 text-primary' />
                                {/* <p className='tipografia font-bold text-xl text-primary'>Password</p> */}
                                <input
                                    type={showpassword === true ? 'text' : 'password'}
                                    name="firstName" placeholder='Password'
                                    value={inputs.password}
                                    className="inputs tipografia font-bold text-base "
                                    onChange={(e) => setInptus({ ...inputs, password: e.target.value })}
                                    required={true} />
                                {showpassword === false ? <EyeSlashIcon onClick={showPassword} className='w-9 h-7 cursor-pointer text-primary' /> :
                                    <EyeIcon onClick={showPassword} className='w-9 h-7 text-primary cursor-pointer' />
                                }
                            </div>
                            {/* btn login */}
                            <button type='submit'
                                className='bx-btn-login  tipografia text-xl font-extrabold text-branco flex justify-center items-center'
                                onClick={(e: any) => handleLogin(e)}>
                                Login
                            </button>
                        </form>
                        {/* recover password */}
                        <div className='line-horizontal border-t-2  border-branco' />
                        <div className='flex justify-center  items-center recover '>
                            <p className='tipografia text-branco font-bold lg:text-base xs:text-sm   cursor-pointer'>RECUPERAR A PASSWORD ?</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>)

my app  /src/app/__app.tsx
import Image from "next/image";
import React from 'react';
import type { AppProps } from 'next/app'

// import Principal from "@/src/pages/index"
// import { AuthProvider } from '../src/context/AutherContext'
import { AuthProvider } from '@/context/AutherContext'
import Login from '../pages'



export default function App({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  return (

    <AuthProvider>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
      <Login />
    </AuthProvider>

  );
}

Here is the project code, if necessary I can provide more details

When using contexts in React, you provide the context as props to the provider, e.g.:
const login () => {
  // login logic
};
return (
  <AuthProvider login={login}>


yes, I provide data through my context   export const AuthContext = createContext({} as any)

This creates the context - but it does not populate it. The context object properties get set by the Provider. Your call to createContext initializes the context as an empty object, to give the context values you add them as props to the provider
